# How to rerun only failed tests with FitNesse?

Tags: fitnesse-slim

I am unable to figure out how to filter out tests based on their run statuses in FitNesse. I'm commenting out all the passed tests manually so that the next run can ignore them. How can I only rerun failed tests?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature in FitNesse to do this.  Usually you want to keep running passed tests to ensure that nothing has caused them to break.